# Inventory Balance stock display

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, inventory

I have come across a small problem where I have to show the Display of Items in Inventory through a query. I am retrieving data from 4 tables and want the output similar to below displayed. the table structures and sample values have been given in **SQL fiddle**. Here is a **[SQL Fiddle for the table structures an values.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f977e/1/0)**

The output what I want is like this.

```
Date                    ItemName        Rate     InQty  OutQty  Balance ItemUnit
2013-01-04 00:00:00.000 Sand            0.000    10    5        5       NONE
2013-01-04 00:00:00.000 Backhoe Loader  650.000  20    2        18      Hr
2013-01-04 00:00:00.000 Tractor Troley  150.000  10    0        10      Hr

2013-02-04 00:00:00.000 Sand            0.000    0     5        0       NONE
2013-02-04 00:00:00.000 Backhoe Loader  650.000  5     2        21      Hr
2013-02-04 00:00:00.000 Tractor Troley  150.000  10    30       -10     Hr
.
.
.
```

I have spend more then a month doing this. Can any body please help me?

Comment: And *what exactly* is the **question** here?!?!?!?

Comment: the ques is i want the sample output as the above displayed, i have written query and table structures in the sql fiddle link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f977e/1/0
, can u please help me? I am editing my ques

Comment: Can you please explain the logic behind the output that you want?

Comment: the logic is that i want to see the items that are IN,OUT and BALANCE on every date, for this i have to retrieve the data from 4 tables. can you help me build query for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this: <s>http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f977e/50</s>

Removed the `MIN()` from the dates as it restricted the data. Added `dateadd-datediff` to make sure all times on dates are removed.
I commented the `where` clause as you see. But you can add it again of course.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT :**

Added grand total.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f977e/75

Comment: yes it is almost what i want, but it will be great if we can add 1 more column as grand balance which can show the grand balance as the total amount which is available in our inventory example balance of 1-1-13+balance of 1-2-13=grand balance, see the balance column in the question.

Answer (score 0):

<s>Try this `Query`:</s>

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT
CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(DATE,I.[Date]),101) AS [Date],
I.Nameofitem AS ItemName,
I.Rate AS RATE,
I.Qty AS InQty,
ISNULL(O.Qty,0) AS OutQty,
ISNULL(I.Qty,0)-ISNULL(O.Qty,0) AS Balance,
O.unit AS ItemUnit
FROM Outwards_Master O
RIGHT JOIN Inwards_Master I ON O.Nameofitem=I.Nameofitem
                                AND CONVERT(DATE,O.[Date])=CONVERT(DATE,I.[Date])
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f977e/7)**

**Note:** This will not produce the exact **output** as the data defer.

**Edit:**

**Assumptions (which i think is there in your *Structure*)**

1.All the **Date** in **Inward Master** and in **Outward Master** are **same** and **vice-versa** AND **Date** IS `PRIMARY KEY`

2.Each and every Item has **Inward** and **Outward Quantity Column** for every **Date**

With above assumption here is the `SQL Query`

1.The **TEMP Table**

```
SELECT 
DENSE_RANK() over(order by I.Date) AS [RANK],
ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by I.Date order by I.Date) AS [VersionId],
I.Date,
I.Nameofitem,
I.Rate,
ISNULL(I.Qty,0) AS INQTY,
ISNULL(O.Qty,0) AS OUTQTY,
I.unit
INTO #TEMP1
FROM 
#Inwards_Master I
INNER JOIN #Outwards_Master O ON CONVERT(DATE,O.[Date])=CONVERT(DATE,I.[Date])
            AND I.Nameofitem=O.Nameofitem

SELECT * FROM #TEMP1 ORDER BY Date,Nameofitem
```

2.The Balance:

```
;WITH x AS
(
    SELECT 
        [Rank],
        [VersionId],
        Nameofitem,
        [Date],
        INQTY,
        OUTQTY,
        bal=(INQTY-OUTQTY)
    FROM #temp1
    WHERE [Rank] = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        y.[Rank],
        y.[VersionId],
        y.Nameofitem,
        y.[Date],
        y.INQTY,
        y.OUTQTY,
        x.bal+(y.INQTY-y.OUTQTY)
    FROM x INNER JOIN #temp1 AS y
    ON y.[Rank] = x.[Rank] + 1
    AND y.VersionId=x.VersionId
    and y.Nameofitem=x.Nameofitem
)
SELECT 
    [Date],
    Nameofitem,
    INQTY,
    OUTQTY,
    Balance = bal
FROM x
ORDER BY Date,Nameofitem
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 10000);
```

**[Here is the SQL Fiddle to verify](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/88bb1/1)**

Comment: thank you, but i also want the previous day's balance to be added in the present day and show the total balance i.e. the last shown balance must show the total balance after all the INs, OUTs of all the previous days, and 1 more thing i have different tenders but i want to see only the requires tender's data not all, can u suggest any change?

Comment: I just came now. Let me See if i can do that.

Comment: thank u once again I'll be very pleased to have this thing solved.