# Stock Vertical to Horizontal in sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server, crystal-reports

i am using sql server 2012/14.
i need to calculate Cylender holding stock report  which supply input customer code and period of date i.e from Date and ToDate.

my DDL

```
CREATE TABLE #CylenderHolding
 (
  CUSTCODE varchar(50)
 , AUDTATE DATETIME
 ,INVOICENUMBER VARCHAR(25)
    ,RECIPTNUMBER VARCHAR(25)
 ,ITEM VARCHAR(25)
 ,[INQTY] INT
 ,[OUTQTY] INT

 )

 INSERT INTO #CylenderHolding 

 values('CUST0013', '2017-01-01 00:00:00' ,'' ,'RECIP001' ,'CYLINDER01'  ,10 ,0),
     ('CUST0013', '2017-01-10 00:00:00' ,'INV0001' ,'' ,'CYLINDER01'  ,0 ,5),
    ('CUST0013' ,'2017-01-02 00:00:00' ,'' ,'RECI0002' ,'CYLINDER02'  ,15 ,0),
    ('CUST0013' ,'2017-01-20 00:00:00' ,'INV0002' ,'' ,'CYLINDER02' ,0 ,7),
  ('CUST0013' ,'2017-02-01 00:00:00' ,'' ,'RECIP003' ,'CYLINDER01' ,4 ,0),
    ('CUST0013' ,'2017-02-05 00:00:00' ,'' ,'RECIP004' ,'CYLINDER02' ,4 ,0),
   ('CUST0013' ,'2017-02-18 00:00:00' ,'INV0003' ,'' ,'CYLINDER01' ,0 ,4),
       ('CUST0013' ,'2017-02-18 00:00:00' ,'INV0004' ,'' ,'CYLINDER01' ,0 ,2),
   ('CUST0013' ,'2017-02-18 00:00:00' ,'INV0004' ,'' ,'CYLINDER02' ,0 ,4)

  select * from #CylenderHolding order by  AUDTATE,ITEM
  drop table #CylenderHolding

>
```

---

i  have given two types of input i.e

Customer :CUST0013    FromDate: 1 Jan 17 To 31-Jan-17

Customer :CUST0013    FromDate: 1 Feb 17 To 28-Feb-17

expecting output

[image]

i am expecting  output in either in Sql or Crystal Report or .net(C#)
Balance Formula = ( Previous Balance + In) - Out

i have uploaded dll with image you click on following link
[enter link description here](https://docs.google.com/document)

similar post  it [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15940565/inventory-balance-stock-display)

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15940565/inventory-balance-stock-display)

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please elaborate.

Comment: When looking at your report and your data, what are you trying to achieve? The columns are not making sense at an aggregation point of view. Also, your Invoicenumber/ReciptNumber are looking quite the same in some parts. Please clarify!

Comment: your sample data and image data  are not in  tandem.Atleast provide same image data.

Comment: i have edited query and uploaded expected output plz check it